# creating a cookie that stores data sitewide issue

Tags: wordpress, cookies, path

I am using this script in an attempt to set the visibility styling of a div and store it as a cookie, site-wide. My understanding is that path=/ should set the cookie to store at the root and thus be available to all pages - passing the value to the other pages to either keep the div's visibility, visible or hidden, depending on the users preference. However, checking the output, it appears as though the cookie is only being stored 'per-page'. What am I missing? I have placed the script in the header and it is loaded on every custom post/page of my wp theme. (*omitted*) - there is a toggle button top left of the page, show/hide comments.

```
// Placed above </head> tag on my header-webmockups.php file
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( function () {
        var toggle = $( '.toggle' );
        var comments = toggle.find( '.comments' );
        if ( $.cookie( 'divState' ) == 'visible' )
            comments.show();
        else
            comments.hide();
        toggle.find( 'a' ).click( function () {
            if ( comments.is( ':visible' ) )
                $.cookie( 'divState', 'hidden' );
            else
                $.cookie( 'divState', 'visible' );
            comments.toggle();
        } );
    } );
    $.cookie( "divState", 1, {
        expires: 10000
    } );
</script>

// Placed at the top of my comments.php loop (toggle div closes after page content)
<div class="toggle"><a>Show/Hide Comments</a>

// Placed after <?php wp_head(); ?> of post's custom header.php
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery-cookie", get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/lib/jquery.cookie.js', array( 'jquery' ), '0'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add expiration date to your cookie.
For example

```
$.cookie("test", 1, { expires : 10000 });
```

As i see from your URL and code, you haven't set it and it works in current session only.

[image]

So after all your script block should look like so: (remove current block entirely and  paste this one)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( function ($) {
            var toggle = $( '.toggle' );
            var comments = toggle.find( '.comments' );
            if ( $.cookie( 'divState' ) == 'visible' )
                comments.show();
            else
                comments.hide();
            toggle.find( 'a' ).click( function () {
                if ( comments.is( ':visible' ) )
                    $.cookie( 'divState', 'hidden', {expires: 10000, path: '/'} );
                else
                    $.cookie( 'divState', 'visible', {expires: 10000, path: '/'} );
                comments.toggle();
            } );
        } );
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have added the session time, removed the cookie script and replaced it with jquery.cookie.js, but still don't seem to understand why the cookie is still being handled no a page/page basis. Being a web designer - my coding skills are rather noob. Your comment about adding the time prompted me to attempt to add the path:'/' in a similar fashion, $.cookie("divState", 1, {path:'/'}); or adding $.cookie("divState", 1, {expires: 1000, path:'/'});  but only ended up breaking the script. :/

Comment: ah, okay - I think I see what your doing there - your passing both the exp & path in the same string, i think, lol... Works! Thank you so much, I really appreciate your 'help' on this. ;)